# iText 7 print pdf direcly

Tags: vb.net, itext, itext7

I've a function in vb.net which generates a PDF file, but I want to print it direcly to the printer... I tried to print via procress/chrome using that code

```
    Dim processo As New Process()
        processo.StartInfo.FileName = chromePath
        processo.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("--kiosk-printing ""{0}""", caminhoArquivoPDF)
        processo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        processo.Start()
```

No success... Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just print it first, then generate the PDF?

Comment: Because I generate the PDF first with iText... Then I need to print this PDF file...